# Parse json NSlog xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have gotten this JSON data back and I would like to parse it into the 3 categories: "guid", "exponent", and "modulus". How would I do that? Thank you for the help in advance!

> 2015-07-01 11:02:51.972 Acculunk KeyPad[4717:1667358] Response Body:
>   {"error_code":0,"error_message":"","exponent":"010001","guid":"855fd04f-0016-1805-a3be-84dbef17ffd6","modulus":"C44274FBD65D79B7F9ADF5255A563A5B8B8438D30F8E2CAD16950BE8675827B94F4F8040D4A9563811F405F8E94A20A69DCC0CA590F8731803AB4682497C0DC2520AD2AEB2CC4ED159276335C83B4FB4CB44966448081C625DF88D019118B7448684743EFB6D6704F8F8BD79875ACAEFC541DA3661D0D00BDDF115382A64C5C5","tran_id":"cb2e8149-4961-458a-a6b2-7443bdb01509"}
>   2015-07-01 11:03:37.175 Acculunk KeyPad[4717:1674710] Terminating since there is no system app.

Here's the code:

```
NSString *temp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n  \"partner_key\": \"%@\",\n  \"auth_token\": \"QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl\",\n  \"payment_account_id\": \"%@\",\n  \"card_number\": \"%@\",\n  \"card_exp_date\": \"%@\",\n  \"amount\": \"%@\",\n  \"memo\": \"%@\",\n  \"recipient\": {\n    \"email\": \"%@\",\n    \"mobile_phone\": \"%@\"\n  }\n}",[Partner_Key text], [Payment_Account_ID text], [Card_Number text], [Card_Exp_Date text], [Amount text],[Memo text], [Recipient_Email text], [Recipient_Phone_Number text]];
NSLog(temp2);

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://cert.payzur.com/payzurservices.svc/payment/send/initiate"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:[temp2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                  if (error) {
                                      // Handle error...
                                      return;
                                  }

                                  if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                                  }

                                  NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                  NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);

                                  NSData *jsonData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                  NSError *e;
                                  NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:body options:nil error:&e];
                                  if (res) {
                                      NSNumber *errorCode    = res[@"error_code"];

                                      NSString *errorMessage = res[@"error_message"];

                                      NSString *guid         = res[@"guid"];

                                      NSString *exponent     = res[@"exponent"];

                                      NSString *modulus      = res[@"modulus"];

                                  }
                                  else {
                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                  }




                              }];
[task resume];
```

Comment: JSON parsing has never been done anywhere. What have you tried? There are plenty of questions, explanations, tutorials about parsing JSON.

Comment: Use `+ JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+ JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` to create a `NSDictionary` of the JSON.

Then access the elements in the usual manner of accessing dictionary items.

Answer by Christopher Mäuer using the literal syntax:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:apiReturn options:0 error:&error];
if (res) {
    NSNumber *errorCode    = res[@"error_code"];
    NSString *errorMessage = res[@"error_message"];
    NSString *guid         = res[@"guid"];
    NSString *exponent     = res[@"exponent"]; // Maybe also a NSNumber?
    NSString *modulus      = res[@"modulus"];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Updated for new question code:

Here is sample code, I have re-constructed the data received from the log out put in the question:

```
NSString *responseBody = @"{\"error_code\":0,\"error_message\":\"\",\"exponent\":\"010001\",\"guid\":\"855fd04f-0016-1805-a3be-84dbef17ffd6\",\"modulus\":\"C44274FBD65D79B7F9ADF5255A563A5B8B8438D30F8E2CAD16950BE8675827B94F4F8040D4A9563811F405F8E94A20A69DCC0CA590F8731803AB4682497C0DC2520AD2AEB2CC4ED159276335C83B4FB4CB44966448081C625DF88D019118B7448684743EFB6D6704F8F8BD79875ACAEFC541DA3661D0D00BDDF115382A64C5C5\",\"tran_id\":\"cb2e8149-4961-458a-a6b2-7443bdb01509\"}";
NSData *data = [responseBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// The above was just to get `data` setup.

// The only function of the following two statements is to print the data as a string.
NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);
//
// NSData *jsonData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"res: \n%@", res);

if (res) {
    NSNumber *errorCode    = res[@"error_code"];
    NSString *errorMessage = res[@"error_message"];
    NSString *guid         = res[@"guid"];
    NSString *exponent     = res[@"exponent"];
    NSString *modulus      = res[@"modulus"];
    NSLog(@"errorCode: %@\nerrorMessage: %@\nguid: %@\nexponent: %@\nmodulus: %@", errorCode, errorMessage, guid, exponent, modulus);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Output:

```
Response Body:
{"error_code":0,"error_message":"","exponent":"010001","guid":"855fd04f-0016-1805-a3be-84dbef17ffd6","modulus":"C44274FBD65D79B7F9ADF5255A563A5B8B8438D30F8E2CAD16950BE8675827B94F4F8040D4A9563811F405F8E94A20A69DCC0CA590F8731803AB4682497C0DC2520AD2AEB2CC4ED159276335C83B4FB4CB44966448081C625DF88D019118B7448684743EFB6D6704F8F8BD79875ACAEFC541DA3661D0D00BDDF115382A64C5C5","tran_id":"cb2e8149-4961-458a-a6b2-7443bdb01509"}

res: 
{
    "error_code" = 0;
    "error_message" = "";
    exponent = 010001;
    guid = "855fd04f-0016-1805-a3be-84dbef17ffd6";
    modulus = C44274FBD65D79B7F9ADF5255A563A5B8B8438D30F8E2CAD16950BE8675827B94F4F8040D4A9563811F405F8E94A20A69DCC0CA590F8731803AB4682497C0DC2520AD2AEB2CC4ED159276335C83B4FB4CB44966448081C625DF88D019118B7448684743EFB6D6704F8F8BD79875ACAEFC541DA3661D0D00BDDF115382A64C5C5;
    "tran_id" = "cb2e8149-4961-458a-a6b2-7443bdb01509";
}

errorCode: 0
errorMessage: 
guid: 855fd04f-0016-1805-a3be-84dbef17ffd6
exponent: 010001
modulus: C44274FBD65D79B7F9ADF5255A563A5B8B8438D30F8E2CAD16950BE8675827B94F4F8040D4A9563811F405F8E94A20A69DCC0CA590F8731803AB4682497C0DC2520AD2AEB2CC4ED159276335C83B4FB4CB44966448081C625DF88D019118B7448684743EFB6D6704F8F8BD79875ACAEFC541DA3661D0D00BDDF115382A64C5C5
```

Comment: It looks like my data is a NSString not an NSdata. Do you know what i can do since its a string?

Comment: `NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` But why does it look like a string and not data? There are no quotes around it, the outer characters are {} which would indicate a dictionary. OTOH NSLog'ed dictionaries usually do not quote strings that do not have space characters in  them. How did you get it?

Comment: So I would be inserting that before everything you gave me? I got the json data back after calling an api and it got saved in body just like this

 NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);

Comment: Just use `data `, there is no need to convert it to a string and back. The string representation is good for logging.

Comment: I can post my code in another comment and then you can see what I did wrong if you're not busy. I really truly do appreciate the help!!

Comment: Add the code to the question, you can edit your oen question.

Comment: Wait so how would I just leave it as data instead of making it into a string? The program I got the api, gave me this code..

Comment: Ok, I posted it! Thank you so much! If you have gmail we could chat about it instead of making this thread longer if you're free?

Comment: Hey Ralph, I still have an error saying that "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void' to parameter of type 'NSJSONReadingOption" and also incompatible pointer typer sending 'NSSTRING' to parameter to type "NSDATA'

Comment: Pass `0` not `void` as the `NSJSONReadingOption`.

Comment: Only problem is that I I don't even see NJSONReadingOption in my code?

Comment: You need to look at the documentation: `+ (id nullable)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData * nonnull)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError * nullable * nullable)error`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what that means.. I'm sorry to bother you so much, thank you for all the help and I'll vote you for best answer at the end

Comment: That is the declaration if the `JSONObjectWithData` method. The `option` parameter takes a type of `NSJSONReadingOptions` or 0. Things will be a lot ewasier if you spend some time studying Objective-C, Apple and others provide some good docs, I have.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! The last question I have is do you know how to make the request synchronus because it looks like my code is jumping ahead and is failing because it doesn't have the information and its just passing in as nil.

Comment: You really don't want to do that, if the site is slow or times out the app will be hung and non-responsive. One way around this is to send a NSNotification to a method that will use the received information. But if you have to you can use the `NSURLConnection` method `sendSynchronousRequest:`. Note that this method is deprecated in iOS9 but should continue to be supported for years.

Comment: Could you help me write the NSNotification? Thank you so much, I'm learning more from you than I would've just watching nonstop youtube. Hopefully one day I can be as knowledgeable as you are.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, this data comes as type NSData, you can do the following:

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:apiReturn options:0 error:&myError];

NSNumber *errorCode = res[@"error_code"];
NSString *errorMessage = res[@"error_message"];
NSString *guid = res[@"guid"];
NSString *exponent = res[@"exponent"]; // Maybe also a NSNumber?
NSString *modulus = res[@"modulus"];
```

The Data will be available in the five variables:

- errorCode
- errorMessage
- guid
- exponent
- modulus

Comment: Good, it could be also shorter `NSNumber *errorCode =res[@"error_code"];`

Comment: Why `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves`?

Comment: Use the literal syntax, it has been available for several years now. Also there is no need to cast in this instance. Less code it better, clearer ti understand, fewer potential errors.

Comment: See the first comment. Also see [literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Comment: Oh, right. Yes thanks. Learned something new today :)

Comment: It looks like my data is a NSString not an NSdata. Do you know what i can do since its a string?

Comment: completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

There you have your NSData *data!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you replacing the following two lines:

```
NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);
```

With the two code lines I provide:

```
     NSError *error;
     NSDictionary* responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

or with the following:

```
     NSDictionary *responseData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)data];
```

So now you have a `NSDictionary`, which is `responseData`, so now we can decode your JSON response as follows (I will put the whole code as follows):

```
     NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSDictionary *responseData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)data];

     NSString *guid = [responseData valueForKey:@"guid"];

     NSString *exponent = [responseData valueForKey:@"exponent"];

     NSString *modulus = [responseData valueForKey:@"modulus"];


     NSLog(@"Decoded Response :\n guide : %@,\n exponent : %@,\n modulus : %@", guid, exponent, modulus);
```

So your whole code which you have pasted above in your Question will look like following:

```
NSString *temp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n  \"partner_key\": \"%@\",\n  \"auth_token\": \"QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl\",\n  \"payment_account_id\": \"%@\",\n  \"card_number\": \"%@\",\n  \"card_exp_date\": \"%@\",\n  \"amount\": \"%@\",\n  \"memo\": \"%@\",\n  \"recipient\": {\n    \"email\": \"%@\",\n    \"mobile_phone\": \"%@\"\n  }\n}",[Partner_Key text], [Payment_Account_ID text], [Card_Number text], [Card_Exp_Date text], [Amount text],[Memo text], [Recipient_Email text], [Recipient_Phone_Number text]];
NSLog(temp2);

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://cert.payzur.com/payzurservices.svc/payment/send/initiate"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:[temp2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                  if (error) {
                                      // Handle error...
                                      return;
                                  }

                                  if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                                  }

                                  NSDictionary *responseData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)data];

                                  NSString *guid = [responseData valueForKey:@"guid"];

                                  NSString *exponent = [responseData valueForKey:@"exponent"];

                                  NSString *modulus = [responseData valueForKey:@"modulus"];


                                  NSLog(@"Decoded Response :\n guide : %@,\n exponent : %@,\n modulus : %@", guid, exponent, modulus);



                              }];
[task resume];
```

Comment: After entering changing what you gave me, I got a thread 4: breakpoint error at the NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; even after the edited post you provided me.

Comment: Hey, I'm telling you to remove that line which you have used to convert the `NSData` variable `data` and put my code lines to convert that `data` variable to `NSDictionary`!

Comment: I updated my answer to be more helpful to you to understand it!

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, after taking what you gave me and putting it in, I got a signal SIGABRT error and got this error. Thank you so so much for the help I really appreciate it 

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:]: dictionary argument is not an NSDictionary'

Comment: Oh, if you got a warning saying, `argument is not an NSDictionary` then let's replace this line in my above pasted code: `NSDictionary *responseData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)data];` with the following: ` NSError *error;
     NSDictionary* responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];`

Hope this might help, if not I'm sorry!

Comment: Sorry, I got even more error such as interface type cannot be statically allocated, implicit conversion of an object-c pointer to 'NSError@_autoreleasing is disallowed with ARC"

Answer (score -1):

Well, you didn't say anything about how you got the data back, like if you already have it in a NSString or still in NSData, so I'm going to assume you have it in NSData.

```
NSData *json <- somehow I magically got jSON data into this
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSString guid = [NSString stringWithString:jsonDict[@"guid"];
NSString exponent = [NSString stringWithString:jsonDict[@"exponent"];
NSString modulus = [NSString stringWithString:jsonDict[@"modulus"];
```

Comment: There is no need for `stringWithString`, that does nothing. It almost seems like devs want to make things more complicated than necessary. ;-) The code also has several syntax errors. `kNilOptions` is a nice touch.

Comment: @zaph I guess I'll have to double check, but the way objective-c handles objects I like to make sure I have my own copy of the string rather than counting on a pointer to the original inside the Dictionary.

Comment: The original is not "inside the Dictionary", the Dictionary just has a pointer to it. On assignment the variable also has a pointer to it, there is no "ownership". There is also no reason to believe that `stringWithString` actually creates a new copy. They are immutable so there is no issue with sharing. But you  still have syntax errors, missing closing brackets pointer "*" missing; consider fixing them.

Comment: Just tested using Xcode 6.4, `stringWithString:` does not create a copy.